# How can we upload video assets to candymachine?

Tags: metaplex

I need to upload video assets to candymachine but I didn't find anything related to it in metaplex docs. Please can anyone assist with it?

Answer (score 3):

I'll explain how to do it with [sugar](https://docs.metaplex.com/tools/sugar/), since this is the current recommended tool for creating candy machines (CM). I'll also assume that you are already aware how to create a CM with images in it and how to [properly prepare the assets](https://docs.metaplex.com/developer-tools/sugar/guides/preparing-assets) for it and that you are using MP4 video files.

Even for video NFTs you should include a PNG image into the asset folder and json to have a placeholder image for wallets / dapps that are unable to render video files.

In addition to the process of creating a CM containing images you'll have to do two steps:

1. Like shown in the [token metadata standard](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/token-standard#the-non-fungible-standard) add a animation URL to your json file:

```
{
...
  "image": "0.png",
  "animation_url": "0.mp4",
...
}
```

2. Include your mp4 video files into the same asset folder where you also have the PNG and JSON files.

And that's it!